# Why are hotels in Paris too expensive?

Tags: france, safety, hotels, paris, price

I am planning on vacationing in Paris for a few days and really have a problem with these expensive hotels. I have two options:

1. Pay too much, at least 220€/night and stay in comfortable/safe hotel.
2. Save money and stay in a potentially uncomfortable/unsafe hotel.

I am nervous about the cleanliness and safety of the less expensive hotels? I want something clean (at least a 3 stars) and not so expensive.

Are there any other options for me?

Comment: This question does not seem to be about safety, like you have tagged it. Are you asking specifically about Paris (in which case the question should be so tagged) or about hotels in big cities generally (which may be too broad for a question)?

Comment: The answer to your title question is: they are not _too_ expensive. They are just right expensive. They fill their rooms at the rate they charge, and therefor are charging that rate.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I interpret this to mean that the OP considers the mid-town hotels 'safe' due to their location and clientele, but for the OP to be able to afford the rates, he/she would have to head out to the suburbs where the hotels may be .... 'sketchier' with corresponding ... 'sketchier' clientele.

Comment: Color me bewildered: Paris hotels are a *bargain* compared to London, Zürich, New York, San Francisco.

Comment: Hotel prices follow economics of supply and demand. As long as people pay the asked price, they will charge that much. You can change locations further out or dates when there are fewer tourists to compete with less demand.

Comment: You could try a Radisson Blu hotel, they often have offers where you can pay fully or partially with Club Carlson points, or get a cheap advance payment deal. Sometimes when the cheapest room is €200, you can still book a room for, say, €80 and 20,000 points per day.

Comment: @CountIblis Also pretty much any hotel chain lets you do this if you have points with them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get a dramatic reduction in price without sacrificing comfort and safety by selecting a Paris suburb that has good Metro connections...

[Saint-Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Cloud) is a short walk to 'Boulogne-Pont de Saint-Cloud' metro station and a quick search locates decent hotels starting at about EUR 85.

[La Défense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_D%C3%A9fense) has its own metro station and a quick search locates brand name hotels starting at about EUR 100 (better deals on the weekends)

[Sèvres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A8vres) has brand name hotels in the same price range as Saint-Cloud, but requires a 15 minute walk across the bridge to reach the metro station.

The commute from these places to central Paris ranges from 30 (La Défense) to 60 minutes (Sèvres).

These places are in the western suburbs of Paris. I find that area more appealing for reasons vaguely related to safety and long-standing familiarity (generally not worth going into here), but there would be similar opportunities in the southern suburbs also.

Adding...
The answer to your question: "Why are hotels in Paris too expensive?" is *because they can*.

Comment: *""Why are hotels in Paris too expensive?" is because they can."* Wait until the OP tries to book a hotel in London... hahah. London is a nightmare of uselessly high rent prices.

Comment: This answer is very helpful, La Défense is a very good option

Comment: I have always preferred 2* hotels in Paris to 5*. They are friendly and French, rather than impersonal and American. They might be a bit scruffy, but who cares?